# Some weird scene view glitch

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity when I get close to objects, they start getting cut off until I get to close and then they disappear (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWEzY.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQsji.png).

I tried searching on YouTube, but nothing helped

Comment: You have probably focused an object in the scene using "F". You can [set the clipping planes manually](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/SceneViewCamera.html) or select a different object and press "F" again until it works. The clipping planes in the unity editor where always broken and are a pain to work with, even with the scene camera settings they added in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the result of the camera's Near Clip Plane.

In 3D rendering, cameras have a fixed depth buffer.  That means they can only render what's included in that range of depths.

In your Camera behaviour's settings, you'll see options for adjusting the near and far clip planes, which define the boundaries for the depth buffer.  To fix your problem, you need to make the near clip plane smaller.

While it may be tempting to just make this range huge so everything is included, floating point imprecision will make that cause a rendering glitch known as "z-fighting".  So, you want to define your clip planes in a range that makes sense for your game, but as a general rule of thumb, the far clip plane should be no more than 1000x the near clip plane.